# Minimize Stalling Streaming Video from Google Cloud

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, avkit

#### Problem

Hi everyone. I am streaming video from google cloud storage in my app using AVKit/AVFoundation. Below you can see that I have set `av.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = true` but my video is still stalling often. I know this question will be quite broad because I am a beginner when it comes to streaming video. I do not want to download the videos because it will take to much space in the app.

#### Question

How can I prevent stalling of the video without downloading?

#### My Thoughts

1. It may be an issue with Google Cloud, so I am open to trying something else
2. Maybe there is a better way to perform the networking request
3. Maybe I am not using AVKit/AVFoundation as best as I can

#### My Code

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let av = AVPlayerViewController()
        let urlString = Utilities.shared.lessons![scrollViewIndex].videos[indexPath.row].videoURL
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            av.player = player
            av.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = true
            self.present(av, animated: true) {
                
                av.player!.play()
                
            }
        }
    }
```

urlString is the URL provided by Google Cloud Storage for the video

#### *Edit* Video Specs

[image]

#### *Edit* Networking Info From Xcode

[image]

Comment: Video stalling just means that the video bitrate is higher than the connection is able to deliver. Since we don't know anything about the video you're playing, it's hard to say for certain. In XCode you can inspect the network usage and compare against the (average) bitrate of the video. Also, videos typically have variable bitrate, so the bitrate could spike up at times, which can also be a factor

Comment: @NewDev Thanks for your comment. This helps point me in a direction for what to look into. I will look into this more. I edited the post so that It has the video specs. If you have any other feedback I would love to hear it. Thanks